# Is it possible to create a repeating monthly calendar event on the last 4 days of the month for every month?

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, recurring-events

I am trying to create a calendar that will show freeze dates which are the first 3 day and the last 4 days of the month.  I have not figured out how to do a repeating event that covers the last 4 days as the months have different dates.  I am thinking of using a formula and wanted to see if anyone else had any experience with a repeating event that would be dependent on the last days of the month.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint on-prem or Online? Maybe you can script it?

Answer (score 0):

As @Danny asked can you confirm if you are On-Prem or Online?

You can try scripting it with the REST API, here is a snippet:

```
function createRecurringEvent() {
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var fullUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Calendar')/items";
    var startDate = new Date();
    var endDate = new Date();
    endDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);

    var itemMetadata = {
        "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.CalendarListItem" },
        "Title": "My Recurring Event",
        "EventDate": startDate.toISOString(),
        "EndDate": endDate.toISOString(),
        "fRecurrence": true,
        "RecurrenceData": "<recurrence><rule><firstDayOfWeek>su</firstDayOfWeek><repeat><monthly day='-4,-3,-2,-1' weekdayOfMonth='last' /></repeat><repeatForever>FALSE</repeatForever></rule></recurrence>"
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: fullUrl,
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(itemMetadata),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Successfully created recurring event.");
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log("Failed to create recurring event.");
        }
    });
}
```

This will create a recurring event on the last 4 days of every month. Replace 'Calendar' with the name of your calendar and 'My Recurring Event' with the title of your event.